# DDMS and virtual creator don't work in eclipse

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ddms

I came across few problems with eclipse:
I downloaded android SDK on Linux `(I use ubuntu 11.04)` and ADT plugin.
I start eclipse using terminal and after the eclipse start working in terminal
appears : "Error Loading DDMS Preferences"
Why does the error appear? How to fix that?
Secondly, when i try to set up Android Virtual Device (I fill fields like AVD Name, Device, Target and so on)
and click ok button in 'create new android virtual device (AVD)' window, nothing happens appart 
popping up an error :

`"SDK Manager] Error: null"`

in eclipse console (previous window doesn't disappear)
How to make this creator to work properly?
I am not sure if those two issues have something in common.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting settings file in `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs`

I tried to remove it but it didn't help. What helped though, was to unplug all android devices and then start Eclipse.